# gdalwarp increase resolution

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I currently have a 87Mb Compressed GeoTiff with a resolution of 50m. I need to interpolate this to 2.5m

I have used gdalwarp to achieve this using a cubicspline, but it took 12hrs and resulted in a 44Gb GeoTiff. I did use -co COMPRESS=LZW but wondering if gdal_warp uses these creation options?

I then tried -r average which only took a few hours but still resulted in a 22Gb GeoTiff.

If I look at the results the image still looks very course (granular) even though gdalinfo does say it now has a pixel size of 2.5

Am i doing something wrong or expecting too much from gdal

thanks

Comment: I know this isn't how quite how it works, but you're increasing the raster size roughly by 400 times (20x20 cells of 2.5 versus 1x1 of 50).

Comment: COMPRESS and gdalwarp may not always work, see:
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp
although I'm not sure this applies to your version. You can also use -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS or -wo NUM_THREADS=N to (possibly) speed things up.

Comment: @kyle thanks for the tip about NUM_THREADS very useful. I was using --config GDAl_CACHEMAX 1024 and -wm 1024 which also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gdalwarp` to transfrom a raster from a coarse resolution to a finer resolution will increase the numbers of pixel (in your case by a factor of 400, like mkennedy stated in his comment above). 
If you choose an interpolation technique other from nearest neighbour (`-r near`) the raster will contain different pixel values based on the interpolation result, therefore the raster will look "smoother", but you can not create additional information to get a "sharper" result.
If you need to get a "real" finer resolution you could use for example "pan sharpening" techniques, if you handling multispectral images and a panchromatic image with a higher geometric resolution. For example this [post from Markus Neteler on planet.qgis](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/user/15/tag/remote%20sensing/) offers a quick example for Landsat-OLI data using `GRASS GIS`. But i do not know if have access to a higher resolution image.
So i do not think you are doing something wrong, but perhaps you are expecting to much from `gdal` in this case ;) please correct me if i am wrong!